# Replacement of tag for collection view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used a collection view. How to display different data on next page each time I click on different cell in collection view without using tag as index path.item.

What I have to write in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath method?

I have used one collection view cell in previous page. I just want to know that how to show different data on next page when I click different cell item each time.

Answer (score 2):

From `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` you will get the corresponding cell using `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Then from that cell you can extract the details that you need.